# DataGridView Get ColumnName From Column Tag

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

It's a simple question but after searching a lot I didn't find a solution for it. I want to get `ColumnName` of a `DataGridView` by column tag. I had put tags on each column with column name.

**EDIT:**
Also I store a decimal value in tag.

This is my code:

```
DataGridViewColumn dgCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
dgCol.Name = "MyCol";
dgCol.Tag = 10; 
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgCol );
```

While tag is of type `Object`. Now I want to set value of cell but I had column tag not the name neither I know column index.

```
DataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[" _**Dont Have ColumnName**_ "].Value = 100;
```

But I had column tag. So is there any way from which I got column name from column tag?

Comment: i guess you have provided name for the column as `MyCol` as mentioned in the code you have added

Comment: Cells[0] or whatever is the number of cell

Comment: if this is the code then `DataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells["MyCol"].Value = 100;` should work..

Comment: yes i provide name for column but at runtime i get some decimal value and that value is compared with column tag

Comment: i had almost 90 columns and i didnt get column name runtime i get only  some decimal value which i am comparing with tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through all `columns`:

```
DataGridViewColumn getcol;

foreach(DataGridViewColumn c in DataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if(c.Tag as String == "10")
    {
        getcol = c;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this `getcol`.

```
DataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[getcol.Name].Value = 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

this is an improvement to my previous answer 
You can use **linq** also and it is shorter and neat.

```
    var col = dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Where(c => c.Tag == "10").Single();
    dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[col.Name].Value = "100";
```

Comment: decimal varvalue = 1;  DataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Where(w => w.Tag  == varvalue.ToString()).Single();                                           it gives me error sequence contain no matching error but there is a column whose tag is 1

Comment: try this - dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Where(c => c.Tag.Equals(varvalue.ToString())).First();

Comment: it's still showing error but at this time error is Object Refrence not set to instance of object

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out:**
            you can get columns name by following ways.
            Suppose i have two columns: **col1 and col2**
**1.** Directly using the column object

```
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[col1.Name].Value = "100";
```

**2.** or by directly columns index

```
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name].Value = "100";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: as mentioned in question he don't have any index of column