# Programmatically accessing the col tags in HTML tables with the .net Webcontrols.table

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc, html

According to this webpage:
http://www.html5-tutorials.org/tables/changing-column-width/

There are col tags in the HTML5 table...

---

```
<table width="100%">
        <col style="width:40%">
        <col style="width:30%">
        <col style="width:30%">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <th>Fruits</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

### ....

... but I cannot figure out how to access them via a progmatically created table.

For example, I can create the table like this:

```
Dim Table As New WebControls.Table
Dim Row As New WebControls.TableRow
Dim Cell As New WebControls.TableCell
Cell.Text = "Fruits"
Row.Cells.Add(Cell)
Table.Rows.Add(Row)
```

But how do I gain access to the col tags so that I can add the style info to them?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table(v=vs.110).aspx

Is this even possible with .net?

(language is irreverent - I can translate)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
DataGridViewColumn getcol;

foreach(DataGridViewColumn c in DataGridView1.Column)
{
    if(c.Tag as String == "10")
        getcol = c;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
DataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[getcol.Name].Value = 100;
```

Original Source: 
[DataGridView Get ColumnName From Column Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755979/datagridview-get-columnname-from-column-tag)

Comment: I'm not **quite** sure if this will work... but it looked somewhat close.

Comment: There does not appear to be a "Column" or "Columns" collection in the Table WebControl to loop through.

Comment: That's because there isn't according to the documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table(v=vs.110).aspx 

In fact, they (MS) say the following: "In fact, if substantial modifications are expected, it is recommended that a DataList, DataGrid, or GridView control be used instead of the Table control. As a result, the Table class is primarily used by control developers."